# libExample.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, static-libraries

Any suggestions are welcome......

Hi,

I am getting an error while building my application. The error is
 "libExample.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"

I am using libExample.a a static cocoa library. I can build this library in "Release" and "i386" architecture or "Debug" with "i386" or "x86_64" architecture because its not allowing me to build it in "Release" mode with "x86_64".

But my application needs to be build in "Release" mode with "x86_64" architecture.

When i add this library with different build modes. Its giving me above error while building my Application.

Any one knows how to change the build settings of static library to "Release" with "x86_64" architecture ? I tried a lot but couldn't make it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.